# Column 'user' in group statement is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I need to get USER from cadastro.user (username) and user from posts.user (user id) but both tables has the same name = USER.
How can I make this select work with this duplicate USER?

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.user, cadastro.user, cadastro.nome, cadastro.id 
FROM posts join cadastro 
where posts.user = cadastro.id and posts.user <> '1' 
group by user order by rand()
limit 10
```

Comment: Add the reference to the table that you want to the `group by`.

Comment: This does seem a wee bit obvious

Comment: oh, dont believe I havent noticed this user in group by... 10h in front of a computer... sorry friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.user, c.user, c.nome, c.id 
FROM posts p, cadastro c 
WHERE p.user = c.id and p.user <> '1' 
GROUP BY p.user ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: oh, it is nice! don't I need to use JOIN to get things from two tables?

Comment: not necessarily, but there are some cases when you must use join for example "The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match."  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: You should use `ON` with `JOIN` and not put join conditions in the `WHERE` -- your query is not ANSI compliant and will not work in any other database.  An answer that doesn't point this out is negligent.

Comment: In oracle databases there is a (+)= (for left join.. ) what you can use in WHERE that will not work on other databases, but my query will.

Comment: @C1sc0 . . . `(+)` is so outdated that Oracle replaced it with explicit outer joins before some people on this forum learned how to read.